# Local rings of $V(y^2-x^3)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, localization, local-rings

I want to find the local rings of $V(y^2-x^3)$, and establish if it's isomorphic to $K[x]_{(x)}$, or maybe some other ring which I don't know.
We take $p=(t^2,t^3) \in V$ and we want to find $O_{(t^2,t^3)}(V) \cong \Gamma(V)_{m_p}$ where $m_p$ corresponds to the maximal ideal of $p$ in $\Gamma(V)\cong K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3) \cong K[X^2,X^3]$ where $X$ denotes an indeterminate.
Since $I(\{p\})=(x-t^2,y-t^3)$ I get that $m_p=(\overline{x}-t^2,\overline{y}-t^3)$ which is sent to $(X^2-t^2,X^3-t^3)$ in $K[X^2,X^3]$ so we consider $K[X^2,X^3]_{(X^2-t^2,X^3-t^3)}$ and from now I'm a bit lost. Is what I did so far correct ?

At first I wanted to say that $\Gamma(V)_{m_p}\cong K[X^2,X^3]_{(X^2,X^3)}$, I thought that $m_p$ was sent to $(X^2,X^3)$ but with what I did above I'm not sure of it.

Is it possible to proceed with what I did ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you've done so far is correct.

If $t\neq 0$, then $X=\frac{X^3}{X^2}\in K[X^2,X^3]_{(X^2-t^2,X^3-t^3)}$ and $(X^3-t^3)-X(X^2-t^2)=t^2(X-t)$, so your local ring becomes $K[X]_{(X-t)}$. This is isomorphic to $K[X]_{(X)}$ by the map $X\mapsto X+t$.

If $t=0$, there's not much you can do to simplify $K[X^2,X^3]_{(X^2,X^3)}$.

Comment: When you say it becomes $K[X]_{(X-t)}$ do you mean that there is some isomorphism between them ? It could given by something like $\phi:K[X^2.X^3]_{(X^2-t^2,X^3-t^3)}\to K[X]_{(X-t)}$ with $\phi(\frac{p(X^2,X^3)}{q(X^2,X^3)})=\frac{p(X^2,X^3)}{q(X^2,X^3)}$ (but in $K[X]_{(X-t)}$) which I think is well defined by your second equality. The inverse would be given by $\psi(\frac{p(x):=\sum_{i=0}^na_iX^{i}}{q(x):= \sum_{j=0}^mb_jX^j}$=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^na_i\frac{X^{3i}{X^2i}}{\sum_{j=0}^na_j\frac{X^{3j}{X^2j}}=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^na_iX^{i+2n+2m}}{\sum_{j=0}b_jX^{j+2n+2m}}$

Comment: I'm sorry I can't edit the comment no more, I struggled finding where was the mistake, I hope it's understandable.

Comment: I mean that they are literally equal: $X$ is in that localization. I can't tell what the rest of your comment is about.